# JQuery - lags during animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have to get some effects when content is changing. Here is my jquery-code:

```
function contentHide( parentElement, callback )
{
    parentElement.animate({
        "height" : "hide", "opacity" : 0.0
    }, "slow", "linear", callback);
}

function contentShow( parentElement )
{
    parentElement.animate({
            "height" : "show", "opacity" : 0.7
    }, "slow", "linear");
}
```

And when content is changing I have a big lags. At first seconds on the page everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are very processor power hungry. I've always tried to limit it to animating 1 property at a time (where possible) to limit the cpu pull. for example animate the height then the opacity via the callback, something like;

```
parentElement.animate(
    {"height" : "hide"}, "slow", "linear", function() {
        parentElement.animate({"opacity" : 0.0}, "slow", "linear", callback);
    }
);
```

Comment: Oh, understand! Thank you for reply. But I'll wait a some more time, maybe another stackoverflow-users will find my problems