# Jquery animation speed on firefox

Tags: jquery, performance, firefox, animation

i have a slideshow that makes 10 slices for each image and animate that slices. Ie,opera,chrome runs animations well but in firefox, animation is too slow, i tried with different computers and still same. I create slices with a "for" loop that creates 10 new divs and each div has different background position property. How can i solvee this for firefox? thanks.

i've added some codes

```
//part of creating slices

for(imageN=0;imageN<imageCount;imageN++)
{
$('#image').append("<div name=slices class=slices></div>");
slicesCreate(imageN);
}

//#image is main div contains slice divs.

//Here is sliceCreate function
/*In this function, it takes how many images added to slideshow, takes all 
sources for each image and creates slices*/
function slicesCreate(imageN)
{
var i = 0;
var nleft = 0;
var image= $("#image img:eq("+imageN+")").attr("src");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)

       {

     $('.slices:eq('+imageN+')').append("<div name=slice"+i+" class=slice></div>");
 $(".slices:eq("+imageN+") .slice[name=slice"+i+"]").css({
  backgroundImage: "url("+image+")",
  backgroundPosition:  nleft + "px 0px",
  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  backgroundSize: twidth
     });  

    /*sliceCount is a global variable that calculated when page loaded for display
    resolution*/
    nleft -=sliceCount;

         }

   }


/* And here is one of the animation code, this code runs for every slice */
function animateSlices(current,next,slice,animid,delay)
{

 setTimeout(function() {

$(".slices:eq("+next+") .slice[name=slice"+slice+"]").css({
       display: "block",
           marginTop: "-700px"
});  


$(".slices:eq("+next+") .slice[name=slice"+slice+"]").animate({
marginTop: "0px"

},1000);


   $(".slices:eq("+current+") .slice[name=slice"+slice+"]").animate({
marginTop: "700px"      
},1000);



    }, delay);


}
```

And the function that called when you click animate button

```
function anim()
 {
  if(!animating)
    {
      animating = true;

       var j = 0;
       var delay = 0;
       current = $('.slices:visible').index('.slices');
       var siz = $('.slices').size();
       var cSize = $('.slices:visible').size();
       var txen = 2;
       var rand = parseInt(Math.random()*3);
       var last = $('.slices:last').index('.slices');
       if(cSize>1)
       return;

    //this part is calculating id of next image
     if(siz > 1 && current!= last)
      {
        txen = current + 1;
      }
     else if(siz == 1)
      {
        txen = current;
      }
       else if(siz > 1 && current== last)
      {
       txen = 0;
      }

   //this part is makin next image slices visible and changes z-index for animation
$(".slices:eq("+txen+")").css({
        display: "block",
        zIndex: "92"
}); 

$(".slices:eq("+current+")").css({
         zIndex: "91"
});         

//this part calls animateSlices function for every next image slices 
   for(j=0;j<10;j++)
     {

   $(".slices:eq("+txen+") .slice[name=slice"+j+"]").css({
        marginTop: "0px"
    }); 

         animateSlices(current,txen,j,rand,delay);
    /*current = this image, txen = next image, j = slice number, rand = animation id,  
    delay = delay for animation */
if(rand==0)
delay += 150;
else
delay += 50;

}

}
else
return;

}
```

Edit: I've changed "marginTop" to "top" in animation and position to absolute for each slice, problem solved for now, it is not lagging anymore. I might have had some errors about positioning divs with jquery codes or changing a lot of margins at the same may be reason for some lag but as i said it was happening only in firefox not ie,opera or chrome. Don't know what caused that lag issue but when i solve this i will write my solution here. For now i will change top value insted of marginTop. Thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: Why don't you use http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ?

Comment: How does your animation code really look like? An example would really help understanding the problem.

Comment: you're going to experience different animation speeds in every browser. Take a look at your animation in IE 7 then see how slow you think FF is. Anyhow, you need to paste your animation code cause by your description your method sounds strange to me and I do tons of jquery animations.

Comment: i've added part of codes, that may help for understanding. it creates 1 slices div and 10 slice div for each image then animates each slice.

Comment: I want to see the code that handles the animation. This just looks like the code to create the elements. The speed can vary heavily depending on how you handle this.

Comment: added code that starts animation and plays it.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code I would say the primary reason for lag in animation is that your slices are being added as individual dom elements and the animation is having to not only push those around but operate off non specific selectors...

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you're basically pushing the latest to the top and moving it in view over a 1 second span of time. If this is the case at any point you would only have 2 frames in view at a time, right?

I would create a javascript object and use that to populate 2 specific dom elements for manipulation.

```
<div id="current"></div>
<div id="next"></div>
```

then manipulate the css of these elements through the animation callback and applicable index of your js object.
This example may not reflect your needs but the principal is the same:

```
var slices = {
    current: 0,
    image_arr: new Array(),
    animating: false,
    queue: null,
    delay: 150,
    init: function(){
         // obviously declare these variables and access them relevantly
         for(imageN=0;imageN<imageCount;imageN++)
         {
            this.image_arr.push($("#image img:eq("+imageN+")").attr("src"));
         }
    },
    animate: function(){
        if(!animating)
        {
            this.animating = true;
            // cycle through your image_arr instead of crawling the dom each iteration
            // set jquery animations as expected then re-call function if needed

            $('#current').css('background-image', this.image_arr[current]).delay(50).animate({marginTop: '700px'}, 1000, function(){
                 this.current += 1; // assuming you're using an int to call the index value of image_arr
            });

            $('#next').css({backgroundImage: this.image_arr[current], marginTop: '-700px').delay(50).animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 1000);

            this.queue = setTimeout(function(){
                this.animate();
            }, this.delay);
            //this should obviously be more considerate, but the idea is to recursively call animate until you're through animating
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    slices.init();
});
```

This example is not at all stable or tested and clearly will not work if you copy / paste, but the general idea is to push your slice elements into an array or object. you can of course push an object for each slice into the array as well. Whatever suits your needs.

But this way you don't have to traverse the entire dom on every frame.

I can answer more specifically if you were to say - post a link to your actual animation. Since I don't see it in action I just guessed what I was looking at and I may have got it totally wrong.

Comment: Got your point, thanks for reply, i will try that kind of code and let you know about result.

Comment: i got a solution by replacing "marginTop" to "top" in animation and set position "absolute" for each slice. It seems a temporary solution but works for me. i will try your codes later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

.animate method is kinda processor-power-hungry if you're not being cautious at all, as some other users have found before.

[JQuery - lags during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531339/jquery-lags-during-animation)

[jquery animate running laggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268351/jquery-animate-running-laggy)

So check out if those help you on building the sentences inside your function in an optimal way.